# How to Handle Hidden Field value changed event Globally in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hidden-field

In my case i have one hidden field on each content page. which is same on all content pages in my application ( on each page with same Id) Now i want to handle value changed event of this field. but at global level. dont want to go on each page and write code. Is it possible? how ? Please help me..

Comment: I cannot see your hidden field. Code would be nice. Anyhow, put it in a master page and each page can use that as master and extend it. Now you have it in one place.

Comment: What exactly do you put in the Hidden field? You need to put more details about what exactly is the use case and what you are trying to achieve in terms of functionality. There can be better solutions suggested than hidden fields if you explain the whole use case.

Comment: Actually in our application we used One hidden field.  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value="0" /> . which is on each page. and used for identifying mode like page in update mode etc. but on some cases the developer changes this fields value at content page_load event and now i want to capture this value changed event for log purpose.